# Springboot 2 Oauth2 cannot redirect to SSO client

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth, spring-security-oauth2

I'm current working on the implementation of Springboot 2.x oauth2. But I got some tricky problems.

The project comprises both auth-server and sso-client (GitHub link is provided in the bottom). The problem is: when I entered a protected URL (eg localhost:9000/) it will be redirected to the login page configured in the auth-server. However, it won't redirect back to sso-client after successful login.

Authorization server config for auth-server:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public AuthorizationServerConfig(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
}

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        super.configure(security);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("client")
            .secret("secret")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code")
            .scopes("all")
            .autoApprove(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
}
```

Security config for auth-server:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("root")
            .password(passwordEncoder().encode("root"))
            .roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Security config for sso-client:

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

application.yml for sso-client:

```
auth-server: http://localhost:9090

server:
  port: 9000

security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      client-id: client
      client-secret: secret
      scope: all
      user-authorization-uri: ${auth-server}/oauth/authorize
      access-token-uri: ${auth-server}/oauth/token
    resource:
      token-info-uri: ${auth-server}/oauth/check_token
      preferTokenInfo: false
```

Here is the link to this project: https://github.com/paul8263/SpringBoot2Oauth2

PS: I made it work with spring boot 1.5.8: https://github.com/paul8263/SsoDemo2

I compared the codes with Springboot2 (first link) but I barely noticed any obvious difference.

Could someone help me solve this problem by making the simple demo working? Many thanks.

Comment: how did you solve this issue? Could you please post the answer. Tnx

Comment: Did you find a solution? I ran into the same thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55993503/why-won%c2%b4t-spring-security-5-redirect-back-to-protected-resource-after-login